# Defining homotopy via the “doubling” endofunctor of a simplicial category

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-categories

I am looking for a reference explicitly defining simplicial homotopy
in terms of endofunctors of $\Delta$, and developing homotopy theory in this terms.
The following is a particular question.

Is it possible to rephrase the following definition of simplicial homotopy in e.g. (8.3.11 of An introduction to homological algebra by C. Weibel)
in terms of endofunctors of $\Delta$ ?

> We say $f$ and $g$ are (strictly) simplicial homotopic if if for each
> $p\geq 0$, there exists morphisms $$ h_i=h^p_i:X_p\to Y_{p+1} \text{
>  for } i=0,\ldots,p $$ such that the following conditions hold.
>
> 1. $$\partial_0 h_0=f_p, \partial_{p+1}h_p=g_p;$$
> 2. $$ \partial_ih_j=\begin{cases}h_{j-1}\partial_i & i<j\\ \partial_ih_{i-1} &i=j\\ h_j\partial_{i-1} & i>j+1; \end{cases}$$
> 3. $$ s_ih_j=\begin{cases}h_{j+1}\partial_i & i\leq j\\ h_js_{i-1} & i>j. \end{cases} $$

One way to try to do it is as follows.

Let $[\times 2]:\Delta\to\Delta$ denote the endomorphism "doubling" each linear order:
$$[0\le 1\le \dotsb \le n] \longmapsto [0 \le 0' \le 1 \le 1'\le \dotsb \le n \le n'] $$
$$ f:[0\le 1\le \dotsb \le n]\to [0\le 1\le \dotsb \le m] \,\longmapsto\, f':[0 \le 0' \le 1 \le 1'\le \dotsb \le n \le n'] \to [0 \le 0' \le 1 \le 1'\le \dotsb \le m \le m']$$
$$
f'(i)=f(i), f'(i')=f(i)' \forall 0\leq i\leq n.$$
If I understand correctly the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/428475) by Dmitri Pavlov, a standard argument gives that $Y_\bullet[\times 2]$ is a path object:
$$Y_\bullet\xrightarrow{w_\bullet} Y_\bullet[\times 2]\xrightarrow{p_\bullet}  Y_\bullet\times Y_\bullet$$
where each $w_n:Y_n \to Y_{2n+1}$  corresponds to the map of preorders
$$[0 \le 0' \le 1 \le 1'\le \dotsb \le n \le n']\to [0  \le 1 \le \dotsb \le n] , i,i'\mapsto i $$
"repeating each coordinate twice",
and the projections $p^\text{even}_\bullet,p^\text{odd}_\bullet:Y_\bullet[\times 2]\to Y_\bullet$ are maps "leaving only even/odd coordinates", i.e. are given by
$p_n^\text{even}: Y_{2n+1}\to Y_n $  corresponding to
$$[0  \le 1 \le \dotsb \le n]\to [0 \le 0' \le 1 \le 1'\le \dotsb \le n \le n'], i\mapsto i$$
and
$p_n^\text{odd}: Y_{2n+1}\to  Y_n $
corresponding to
$$[0  \le 1 \le \dotsb \le n]\to[0 \le 0' \le 1 \le 1'\le \dotsb \le n \le n'], i\mapsto i'$$

**Question.** Is it true (under some “niceness” assumptions) that in a simplicial category
for $X_\bullet$ connected,
two maps $f_\bullet,g_\bullet:X_\bullet\to Y_\bullet$ are (strictly) homotopic
iff both maps $ X_\bullet\xrightarrow {f_\bullet}  Y_\bullet$ and $ X_\bullet\xrightarrow {g_\bullet}  Y_\bullet$
factor via $Y_\bullet[\times 2]$ as
$$ X_\bullet\xrightarrow {\tilde h_\bullet} Y_\bullet\circ[\times 2] \xrightarrow{p^\text{even}_\bullet}  Y_\bullet$$
$$ X_\bullet\xrightarrow {\tilde h_\bullet} Y_\bullet\circ[\times 2] \xrightarrow{p^\text{odd}_\bullet}  Y_\bullet$$
where  $p^\text{even}_\bullet:X_\bullet\circ[\times 2]\to X_\bullet$ and $p^\text{odd}_\bullet:X_\bullet\circ[\times 2]\to X_\bullet$
are maps induced by “forgetting” the odd/even half of the “doubled” linear order $0\le 1 \le \dotsb \le n \le 0' \le 1'\le \dotsb\le n'$, as above.

This appears to be true if one of the maps is trivial (i.e. is a map to a point), see [Defining homotopy via endofunctors of a simplicial category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428423/defining-homotopy-via-endofunctors-of-a-simplicial-category).

Comment: An important keyword here is [décalage](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/decalage).

Comment: Could you explain what is the current status of the answer for you? Did you change the question after it?

Comment: I replaced one obviously incorrect description of the ''doubling'' endofunctor by another incorrect description. I think the status of the answer is that it is an answer,

Comment: but I haven't yet understood it. An explicit reference to an explicit definition and treatment of homotopy in terms of this "doubling" functor would still be nice, but it may well follow from the references given.

Answer (score 4):

Once we correct the definition of $[×2]$ to make it a functor (currently it does not preserve identities) by setting $f'=f⊔f$, it is true that the construction described in the main post gives rise to an equivalent notion of homotopy, assuming $Y$ is Kan.

Indeed, $[⨯2]$ is a right Quillen functor from simplicial sets to simplicial sets, with its left adjoint being the unique left Quillen functor that sends $Δ^n$ to $Δ^n\ast Δ^n$, the join of $Δ^n$ with itself.
We also have canonical inclusions given by the adjoints of projection maps in the main post: $X→X\ast X$ can be included as the left or right factor.
The induced natural transformation $X⊔X→X\ast X$ exhibits $X\ast X$ as a (generalized) [cylinder object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cylinder%20object) for $X$, where instead of a genuine codiagonal map $X\ast X→X$ we only have a zigzag $X\ast X→Y←X$, where $X→Y$ is a weak equivalence.  But this is sufficient to answer the original question in the affirmative.

Equivalently, $Y[⨯2]$ together with the two natural maps $Y[⨯2]→Y$ is a (generalized) [path object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/path+space+object).
A bit of elementary model category theory (see the cited articles) then implies that the notion of homotopy induced by this new cylinder (or path) object coincides with the old notion, assuming $Y$ is Kan.

Comment: Thanks! Do your considerations apply to any category $sA$ of simplicial objects of a category $A$ such that $sA$ is  a model category (with Kan meaning fibrant) ?

Comment: @user420620: It applies to any simplicial model category without changes.

Comment: I corrected the definition and use of the "doubling" endofunctor $[\times 2]$. I am not sure it fits your description $f\mapsto f\sqcup f$, one rather needs to use "even and odd coordinates" to be able to simplicially construct $Y_\bullet \to Y_\bullet[\times 2]$.

Comment: Does the "doubling" endofunctor has a name ? Is there a reference describing its properties and the properties of the definition of homotopy in terms of $[\times 2]$ for arbitrary categories of simplicial objects ?

Comment: @user420620: Concerning your new version, Y is a *contravariant* functor on Δ.  So the maps of preorders that induces the “projection” maps $p$ must go in the opposite direction from their current direction.

Comment: @user420620: This endofunctor is basically a special case of the simplicial join construction.  See https://kerodon.net/tag/016K and also https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/join+of+simplicial+sets.

Comment: @user420620: The endofunctor of simplicial sets induced by precomposition with [x2] on \Delta is the case r=2 of the r-fold "edgewise subdivision".  See section 1 of Bokstedt, Hsiang, Madsen, Invent. Math. 111 (465-540) 1993, or section 6.2.1 of Dundas-Goodwillie-McCarthy, "The local structure of algebraic K-theory".  A conceptual precursor is given in appendix 1 of Segal, Invent. Math. 21 (213-221) 1973, with the idea being credited to Quillen.

Comment: Thanks, @Dmitri Pavlov. I still do not understand why the edgewise subdivision is a path object, nor how is it a special case of simplicial join, and I might eventually make a separate question about this.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov; say, let $X_\bullet$ be representable by set $X_0$. What is the "diagonal" map $X_\bullet(1)=X_0\times X_0\to X_\bullet\circ [\times 2](1)=X_0\times X_0\times X_0\times X_0$ ?

Comment: @user420620: The diagonal map is induced by the map of simplices that sends i and i' to i.  The first projection map is induced by the map of simplices that sends i to i.  The second projection map is induced by the map of simplices that sends i to i'.  (These maps go in the opposite direction from what you wrote in your main post.)

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: To make sure:  and so in my example $(a,b)\in X_0\times X_0$ maps to $(a,b,a,b)\in X_0\times X_0\times X_0\times X_0$ ? 
and for you the order is $0\le 0' \le 1 \leq 1' \le ... \le n \le n'$ ? In most references, e.g. by John Rognes, 
a linear order $P$ gets sent to $P\sqcup P$ where each element of the second copy of $P$ is larger than each element of the first copy, which seems different.  (I corrected the post)

Comment: @user420620: I do not understand where X_0⨯X_0 comes from. Are you talking about the diagonal map w:Y→Y[⨯2]? This map sends 1-simplices of Y to 3-simplices of Y, namely, a 1-simplex Δ^1→Y is mapped to the 3-simplex Δ^3→Δ^1→Y, where the map Δ^3→Δ^1 sends i and i' to i.  For any discrete simplicial set X, the diagonal map and the projection maps as described above are equal to the identity map on X because maps Δ^n→X factor through Δ^0 in this special case.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: Yes, I am talking about that diagonal map $w:Y\to Y[\times 2]$. I meant to take  a representable simplicial set $Y_n:=Hom_(sets}(n,X_0)$. Then 1-simplicies of $Y$ are $X_0\times X_0$, and 3-simplicies are $X_0\times X_0\times X_0\times X_0$.

Comment: @user420620: This must be a morphism of simplicial sets Δ^n→X, not a morphism of sets [n]→X_0.  In particular, every morphism of simplicial sets Δ^n→X, where X is discrete, factors as Δ^n→Δ^0→X.  Alternatively, if you really want to work with sets, you can observe that the discrete simplicial set functor is right adjoint to the π_0 functor, so morphisms of simplicial sets Δ^n→disc(X) are in bijection with morphisms of sets π_0(Δ^n)→X, i.e., elements of X_0.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: What is the map  "where the map Δ^3→Δ^1 sends i and i' to i" you referred to ? I assume it is induced by the map $ [0<1<2<3]\to [0<1]$, $0,1\mapsto 0$, $2,3\mapsto 1$ ? The  two maps corresponding to projections are the map Δ^1→Δ^3 given by $[0<1]\to[0<1<2<3]$, one sends $0\mapsto 0, 1\mapsto 2$, and the other one sends $0\mapsto 1, 1\mapsto 3$.

Comment: @user420620: Yes, but the diagonal map as described only defines a morphism of semisimplicial sets.  (The codegeneracy maps are not order-preserving.)  If you insist on working with genuine simplicial sets, then the diagonal must be implemented as a zigzag with a weak equivalence instead.

Comment: @Dmitry Pavlov: "Yes, but the diagonal map as described only defines a morphism of semisimplicial sets." So does this mean that your answer is inaccurate, i.e. the diagonal map $Y\xrightarrow{(id,id)} Y\times Y$ does not factor as $Y\to Y_\bullet\circ[+2]\to Y\times Y$ and thus $Y_\bullet\circ[+2]$ is not a path object as defined on the nlab page you refer to ?
In fact it seems there is no endofunctor $T:\Delta\to\Delta$ such that $Y\circ T$ is a path object in this sense, due to the classification of such endofunctors.

Comment: @Dmitry Pavlov: it seems that at best you can use $Y\circ T$ to define null-homotopy (rather, being homotopic to a map $X\to disc( Y_0)$) e.g. for $T=[+1]$ because $Y\circ [+1]$ is homotopy equivalent to $disc(Y_0)$ and maybe $Y_\bullet\circ [+1]=disc(Y_0)\times_{Y_\bullet} Y_\bullet$ is a subobject of path space $Y^{\Delta[1]}$ induced by maps $\Delta[n]\times \Delta[1]\to \Delta[n+1]$ contracting $\Delta[n]\times \Delta[0]$ for some fixed embedding $\Delta[0]\to \Delta[1]$.

Comment: @user420620: It is a path object in semisimplicial sets.  However, having a diagonal map is not necessary to answer your original question as it is stated.  Indeed, the two projection maps do give rise to the correct notion of a homotopy, the diagonal map is simply not used (or needed).  I clarified my answer, indicating that the diagonal is implemented by a zigzag.

Comment: @Dmitry Pavlov: how do I see that in simplicial sets an identity map $Y_\bullet\to Y_\bullet$ is homotopic to itself using only $Y\circ [+2]$ and the two projection maps ? By my proposed definition it would mean that the diagonal map $Y_\bullet \to Y_\bullet \times Y_\bullet$ factors via $Y_\bullet \circ [+2]$ , no ? Maybe this uses that $Y_\bullet$ is Kan ?