# Defining null-homotopy in terms of endofunctors in an arbitrary simplicial category

Tags: simplicial-stuff, model-categories, simplicial-categories

I am looking for references defining *contractible* or *null-homotopic* in terms of  endofunctors $\Delta\to\Delta$.

Let $[+1]:\Delta\to\Delta, n\mapsto n+1$ be the endofunctor of $\Delta$ adding a new least element. In $X_\bullet\in Ob\, sC$ of a simplicial category $sC$,
the object $X_\bullet\circ [+1]$ is referred to *the simplicial path space* of $X_\bullet$, and comes equipped with two maps
$Y\circ[+1]\xrightarrow{pr_0} disc(Y_0)$ (induced by $[0]\to[0<1<..<n]$) and $Y\circ[+1]\xrightarrow{pr_{1,2,...}} Y$ (induced by $[1<..<n]\to[0<1<..<n]$).

Is it true that in sSets,
$$Y_\bullet\circ [+1]=disc(Y_0)\times_{Y_\bullet} Y_\bullet$$ is a subobject of the path space
$Y^{\Delta[1]}=\operatorname{InternalHom}_{sSets}(\Delta[1],Y_\bullet)$
induced by maps $\Delta[n]\times \Delta[1]\to \Delta[n+1]$ contracting $\Delta[n]\times \Delta[0]$ for some fixed embedding $\Delta[0]\to \Delta[1]$ ? In what generality something like this holds ?

Call a map $X_\bullet  \to Y_\bullet$ *contractible* iff it factors as $X_\bullet\to Y_\bullet\circ[+1]\xrightarrow{pr_{1,2,...}} Y_\bullet$ (if the fact above is true,
in sSets *contractible* means being homotopic to  a map $X_\bullet\to disc(Y_0)$ where $disc(Y_0)$ denotes the constant (discrete) object $(Y_0,Y_0,...)$).
This definition makes sense in any category of simplicial objects.
In what generality does this notion has good properties ?
I am looking for a reference discussing this definition.

This probably easily follows from the reference (Lemma 1.5.1, K.Waldhausen, Waldhausen, Friedhelm
Algebraic K-theory of spaces. Algebraic and geometric topology (New Brunswick, N.J., 1983), 318–419,
Lecture Notes in Math., 1126, Springer, Berlin, 1985.) given by John Rognes in
[Defining homotopy via endofunctors of a simplicial category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428423/defining-homotopy-via-endofunctors-of-a-simplicial-category)
but I am looking now for something mentioning this more explicitly.